# CURDATE() +7 days as a constraint

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to do a data dump into Excel.  One of my constraints isn't working so I am trying to fix it by looking at the SQL code.  I have never used SQL and only know VBA.  This is what I am trying.  I need it to say V_ORDER_LINES.DATE_ITEM_PROM is less then one week from today.

```
SELECT V_ORDER_LINES.ORDER_NO, V_ORDER_LINES.SO_LINE, V_ORDER_LINES.DATE_ITEM_PROM, V_ORDER_LINES.DATE_SHIP, V_ORDER_LINES.PART, V_ORDER_LINES.QTY_ORDERED, V_ORDER_LINES.QTY_SHIPPED
FROM V_ORDER_LINES V_ORDER_LINES
WHERE (V_ORDER_LINES.DATE_ITEM_PROM<{day,7,CURDATE()})
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: It's called Global Shop

Comment: Never heard of it. If the database engine or just the program using it? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're querying MySql then it might look like

```
SELECT order_no, 
       so_line, 
       date_item_prom, 
       date_ship, 
       part, 
       qty_ordered, 
       qty_shipped
  FROM v_order_lines 
 WHERE date_item_prom < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```